# Couldn't Post Data to api using post method

Tags: c#, json, api, http-post

I'm trying to post data to an api using the below request,

```
{
    "authenticate": {
        "apikey": "API KEY"
    },
    "services": [
        {
            "call": "account/all",
            "identifier": {
                "offset": "0",
                "limit": "20"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

but every time i faced an error

> {"authenticate":{"apikey":null,"status":"failed","error":{"code":"E101","message":"JSON
> Error: Syntax error, malformed JSON"}}}

i'm tried this to post the request

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: @viveknuna write() method takes 3 paramter not one so i can't pass one paramter!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string json = "";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync(
        "url", 
         new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
}
```

Comment: tried your code but, response content returned 200 ok , but after reading the content as a stream the same error!

Comment: Use this to get data await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); or without async  response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Comment: yes i'm using readasStringAsync, the returbed data is the error in my question.

Comment: Show the response

Comment: You are getting the json in the c# code of javascript?

Comment: no i got the response as a json also the request is json  and the returned response error is json too.